# How to store user data in an MVC 5 app ? (with Windows auth)

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, custom-authentication

For each user that connects to our MVC app, I need to store several custom properties (like its role, a list of sites he has access to, etc.). I know how to get the values for those properties (from our SQL database); what I need to know is the best practice to keep this "singleton/static/unique" object accessible across each view, and avoid to poll the DB each time.

Our authentication is Windows authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Could be misinterpreting what you are asking, but ViewBag/ViewData are good tools for cross View/Controller data.